# Table "tbl_category" does not have a column named "select"?

Tags: php, yii

How to run 'OR' condition in `model()->findByAttributes()`?

This is my code:

```
 $criteria->condition='url_title_en=:x OR url_title_da=:x';
 $criteria->params=array(':x'=>$_GET['purl_title']);
 $parentcat = Category::model()->findByAttributes($criteria);
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Table "tbl_category" does not have a column named "select".

Comment: what is your desired result...? And you need to show us your Category class and its model() method

Comment: I just need to get category id using $_GET criteria.
`url_title_en`,`url_title_da` are the fields name,I updated my question.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/40238-adding-or-condition/page__view__findpost__p__192543

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OR like this

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select='category_id';
$criteria->condition='url_title_en=:x';
$criteria->addCondition('url_title_da=:x','OR');
$criteria->params=array(':x'=>$_GET['purl_title']);
```

In above code addCondition appends the extra condition with OR operator. Now If you expect multiple records then you can use

```
$parentcat = Category::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

If you expect single record the you can use

```
$parentcat = Category::model()->find($criteria);
```

What you are using here that you are passing criteria to function `FindByAttributes()` which finds records with respect to attributes passed to it. Now you are passing it criteria and it finds first word as "select" because criteria translates your query like `"select * where category_id=3"`. Now `findByAttributes()` take it as an attribute and tries to find it. thats why it shows error that tble_category cant find select.Here is official documentation of yii http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with your code was that you were using `findByAttributes` instead of `findAll`.

```
$criteria            = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = '`url_title_en` = :uri OR `url_title_da` = :uri';
$criteria->params    = array(':uri' => $_GET['purl_title']);
$records               = Category::model()->findAll($criteria);
// print all records fetched.
print_r($records);
```